# What is the threshold of significance when measuring difference in proteins' radii of gyration?

Tags: proteins, statistics

In molecular dynamics simulations of proteins, the radius of gyration is often used to assess protein compactness. Given two proteins, what difference in radii of gyration can be considered significant? 1 angstrom, 5 angstroms, 10 angstroms? Significant meaning: yes it is definitely more compact or no it is definitely not more compact. I have been searching but can't find any reference related to that.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! I think this is actually a statistics question in disguise — whether a difference is significant will depend on the degree of variance in the two values you are comparing! Also note that these answers will always be probabilistic rather than Boolean (yes or no) ... ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Comment: If you need an introduction to statistics, I have found starting with a relatively accessible and reliable source like [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/statistics-probability) to be very helpful.

Comment: @tyersome The question is more about the threshold one should use to apply a statistical test. The test will tell wheater there is a significant difference or not at a given threshold (1 angstrom, 5 angstroms, 10 angstroms). I think a simple t-test is enough. But a which threshold to use is more biology-related.

Answer (score 1):

Given only the difference of two values, you can make no claims about whether those values are significantly different. In order to determine if two proteins have significantly different radii of gyration (*R<sub>g</sub>*), you will need **repeated measures** and a **statistical test**. To demonstrate the kind of analysis you need to do, consider the following examples.

##### Example 1 -- proteins A and B, 12 measurements each, 0.1 Å resolution

**H<sub>0</sub>**: there is no difference in mean *R<sub>g</sub>* between protein A and protein B.

**Data**

| ***R<sub>g</sub>* protein A (Å)** | ***R<sub>g</sub>* protein B (Å)** |
| --- | --- |
| 10.1 | 11.1 |
| 10.2 | 11.2 |
| 10.1 | 11.1 |
| 10.3 | 11 |
| 10.9 | 11.7 |
| 9.8 | 10.8 |
| 9.9 | 10.9 |
| 10 | 11 |
| 10.3 | 11.2 |
| 10.1 | 10.8 |
| 10 | 11.5 |
| 9.5 | 11.1 |

**Summary Statistics**

| ----- | Protein A | Protein B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mean | 10.1 | 11.1 |
| Variance | 0.113 | 0.0706 |

**Results**

For two independent samples, we can perform an [unequal variance t-test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/796/253702). With α = 0.05, we calculate a two-tailed p value of 5.26 × 10<sup>-8</sup>, so the null hypothesis can be rejected. Despite having a difference between means of only 1 Å, proteins A and B have a significantly different mean *R<sub>g</sub>*.

---

##### Example 2 -- proteins C and D, 12 measurements each, 0.1 Å resolution

**H<sub>0</sub>**: there is no difference in mean *R<sub>g</sub>* between protein C and protein D.

**Data**

| ***R<sub>g</sub>* protein C (Å)** | ***R<sub>g</sub>* protein D (Å)** |
| --- | --- |
| 15 | 5.5 |
| 11.5 | 2.4 |
| 12.2 | 13.3 |
| 20.6 | 14.2 |
| 20.2 | 17.2 |
| 11.2 | 12.6 |
| 15.2 | 17.8 |
| 9.3 | 9.9 |
| 10.8 | 10.1 |
| 14.9 | 8.4 |
| 14.2 | 10.4 |
| 8.2 | 4.8 |

**Summary Statistics**

| ----- | Protein C | Protein D |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mean | 13.6 | 10.6 |
| Variance | 15.2 | 22.9 |

**Results**

Applying the same test as in Example 1, we calculate a two-tailed p value of 0.100, and the null hypothesis cannot be rejected. Despite having a difference in means that is 3 times larger than the observed difference for proteins A and B, the large variance in the measured values means that there is no significant difference in the mean *R<sub>g</sub>* for proteins C and D.